# Is there a way to delete all rows that don't have numbers in string

Tags: r

So i've extracted a dataset of customers from our system and i've loaded in this dataset. I need the dataset to only have street names and the postal code with city in order to send out customer letters The names and NA rows need to be removed. i need to remove all empty lines and all names. I only need the address and zip code.

Therefor i need to delete all rows where there isn't a number in it.

[image]

Comment: `df2 <-na.omit(df)`

Comment: That only removes the NA's. I also need to remove the names

Comment: `subset(df, !is.na(3))` or check out `complete.cases` and `drop_na` from (`tidyverse`)

Comment: What do red boxes mean in the attached picture?

Comment: @PoGibas red boxes show the data i wish to keep. I've already found the answer though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer.

```
df[str_detect(df$..., "\\d")]
```